# Check if n intervals overlap in linear time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I came across the following question, which seems to be impossible to solve, as the fastest algorithm I've found for this online is O(nlgn). Is it possible to solve this linearly?

n intervals [ai, bi] are given. (For every i : ai<bi).
It is known that each for each interval bi is an integer between 1 and n^2, and ai is a real number.

We want to decide whether all intervals are distinct (don't overlap) from each other. Describe in words a linear algorithm (θ (n)) for solving the above problem.

For example:
For n = 5:
[0.48,4], [13.31,14], [3.12,5], [8.412,12], [14.27,16]
Here the algorithm will answer no, because the two sections: [3.12,5], [0.48,4] overlap.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort the intervals by their `bi` values.  Since those values are all between 1 and n<sup>2</sup>, you can do this in linear time with a base-n radix sort.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort
2. Check each interval to see if it overlaps the next.

Comment: With `n^2` possible values, wouldn't radix sort be `O(n^2)`?

Comment: I figured out the answer.  You sort first by the least significant digit.  Then you sort by the first digit.  Both passes are `O(n)`.  After the second pass you get data sorted by both digits.